# Why canvas begin path showing error in code?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am learning canvas. And I want to create a circle. But there is an error using "beginPath()".

Here is my code :

HTML:

```
<canvas></canvas>
```

CSS:

```
body{
  margin: 0;
}
canvas {
 /* background: red;*/
}
```

JS:

```
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

var c = canvas.getContext("2D");

c.beginPath();
c.arc(100, 100, 40, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
c.strokeStyle = "#fff";
c.stroke();
```

Minimal Reproduction: https://codepen.io/ishitaray/pen/zYBvjmZ

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Fix:

```
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");

canvas.width = "200";
canvas.height = "200";

var c = canvas.getContext("2d"); //<--- notice instead of "2D"

//console.log(c);
c.beginPath();
c.arc(100, 100, 100, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
c.strokeStyle = "#fff";
c.stroke();
```